# Training AI models to extract text from scanned PDF documents using Python

Tags: python, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, ocr

I am currently doing an OCR project of scanned PDF documents to get information about the Date, Ref No., and Subject. For example in the pictures below. But currently, these fields are not consistent with each other in different files, for example, in some places Vietnamese: Date, number, content, in other places, Ref No./Number, Date/Date: and some other similar cases. Can you guys guide me in the direction of this problem?

[image]

[image]